# How to create a list of items from another list based on if the items are the key of an object? (Lodash preferred)

Tags: node.js, lodash

How to say this in a more eloquent way, preferably using Lodash:

```js
anObject = {
  'a': 'apple',
  'b': 'banana'
};
largeArray = ['a', 'c', 'd'];
emptyArray = [];

for (var s = 0; s < largeArray.length; s++) {
  if (anObject[largeArray[s]]) {
    emptyArray.push(anObject[largeArray[s]]);
  }
}

console.log(emptyArray)
```

Should give me:

```
emptyArray = ['a']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the [intersection()](https://lodash.com/docs#intersection) from the `largeArray` and the [keys()](https://lodash.com/docs#keys) from the `anObject` variable to accomplish this.

```
_.intersection(largeArray, _.keys(anObject));
```

```js
var anObject = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'banana'};
var largeArray = ['a','c','d'];

var emptyArray = _.intersection(largeArray, _.keys(anObject));

console.log(emptyArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lodash for this. Use the built-in [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. This will return a new array without modifying the original.

```
let obj = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'banana'};
let arr = ['a', 'c', 'd'];

let result = arr.filter(item => obj.hasOwnProperty(item));

console.log(result); // ['a']
```

Or, in ES5:

```
var obj = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'banana'};
var arr = ['a', 'c', 'd'];

var result = arr.filter(function(item) {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(item);
});

console.log(result); // ['a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs#filter), [has()](https://lodash.com/docs#has), and [partial()](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) from lodash:

```
_.filter(largeArray, _.partial(_.has, anObject));
```